# How to calculate the size of label based on font size & text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I have added a label on a view in my app.I have given it some size font size as **16.0**.When the text in label is small then it works fine.But when the text is more in label i want label to increase it's height automatically & also update the constraints.So that i don't want any constraints related warnings.What is the best way of doing it?
**Edit**

```
    cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.label_like_count.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.label_like_count sizeToFit];
    NSString *first_like_user=@"Some Name";
    int count=[first_like_user length];
    NSString *like_count=@"12";
    like_count=[like_count stringByAppendingString:@" others like your post"];
    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:@" and "];
    first_like_user=[first_like_user stringByAppendingString:like_count];
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:first_like_user];

    NSAttributedString *attributeStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:8]}];

    [mutableAttributeStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

    [mutableAttributeStr appendAttributedString:attributeStr];
```

**I tried below code**

```
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [first_like_user sizeWithFont:cell.label_like_count.font
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                          lineBreakMode:cell.label_like_count.lineBreakMode];

    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = cell.label_like_count.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    cell.label_like_count.frame = newFrame;

    [cell.label_like_count setAttributedText:mutableAttributeStr];
```

But this does not increase the label height & label does not come into multilines?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify an explicit height constraint, `UILabel`s calculate their height constraints automatically via `intrinsicContentSize`. All you have to do is to determine the label's width (via an explicit width constraint or through left/right edge constraints), and it'll adjust its height based on the content.

Comment: How much height needed to be increased how do i know that.Can you please tell

Comment: Just simply don't constrain the UILabel's height. It'll calculate the necessary constraint to fit its content automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend to add very useful pod to your project:
pod 'UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints'

In your file import necessary headers:

```
#import "UIView+UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints.h"

[label setText:@"some long text"];
CGFloat newHeight = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(expectedWidth, 99999999)].height;    
[label setConstraintConstant:newHeight forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight];
```

Comment: can you provide the fie pod is not wiorking